# Get Server Host Name and IP in Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

How to get mule server host name and ip address in Mule 4 / Dataweave 2. I tried the below but getting null

```
output application/json
import * from dw::Runtime
---
{
"payload" : payload,
"host": prop("server.host"),
"ip": prop("server.ip"),
"timezone": prop("user.timezone")
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
output application/json
---
{
    host:"$(server.host)"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can execute a call to props() to list all the properties that are configured for the server. If those happen to be missing or null , prop('property-name') would yield null in the result.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-runtime-functions-props

Something like this maybe:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Salim I already looked at that. I didn't find any that provides server name or ip In mule 3.X we could get by calling #[server.host] etc

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score -1):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
import java!org::mule::runtime::core::api::util::NetworkUtils
---
(NetworkUtils::getLocalHost()).hostName
```

There's an official help article to answer this question:
https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-obtain-the-Mule-Runtime-hostname-using-DataWeave

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.